# Kак увеличить регистр в массиве в ruby

Tags: массивы, ruby-on-rails, ruby

upcase! не работает помогите пожалуйста в решении проблемы.

Comment: Приведите примеры того, что вы пытались сделать. Сейчас ваш вопрос можно интерпретировать несколькими существенно разными способами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну потому что не стоит его на самом массиве вызывать, ведь у массивов нет метода `upcase`. Нужно вызвать на каждой строке, содержащейся в массиве.

Предполагая, что в массиве только строки, можно пробежаться по всему массиву методом `each`, увеличивая регистр строки на каждой итерации:

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c"]

arr.each do |str|
  str.upcase!
end
```

Если в массиве могут быть не только строки, то можно сначала привести элемент массива к строке, а потом увеличить регистр (хотя это может привести к неожиданному результату):

```
arr.each do |str|
  str.to_s.upcase!
end
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо!!!! Спасибо что вы этом мире есть добрые люди как вы !!! Слава Богу!!!

Comment: @LiveMrak да на здоровье, нам, добрым людям, не сложно. Но благодарить здесь принято галочкой слева от ответа :)

Comment: @LiveMrak текст вопроса уточните, пожалуйста

Answer (score -1):

Если речь таки именно про Rails, то он для строк [добавляет метод](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-mb_chars) `mb_chars`, спасающий при обработке не-ASCII строк

```
>> "Vasya Вася".upcase
=> "VASYA Вася"
>> "Vasya Вася".mb_chars.upcase.to_s
=> "VASYA ВАСЯ"
```

Для массива строк, соответственно, как-то так:

```
arr = ["Vasya", "Вася"]
arr.map! { |x| x.mb_chars.upcase.to_s }
```

Comment: вот только если вы еще до писали так, вообще было супер.   arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
arr2=[]
arr.each do |str|
  str.upcase!  arr2<< str 
end